# Error get value in array when using input checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sample:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="in-category-1" name="post_category[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" id="in-category-2" name="post_category[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" id="in-category-3" name="post_category[]" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" id="in-category-4" name="post_category[]" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" id="in-category-5" name="post_category[]" value="5">
```

And jquery:

```
var selectednumbers = [];
jQuery('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(i, selected) {
   selectednumbers[i] = jQuery(selected).val();
});
alert(selectednumbers);
```

=> error can't get value when checked and uncheck

Comment: Can you explain what the output should be, if the first and last were checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event to get the selected value along with [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method to retrieve your array:

```
jQuery('input[type=checkbox]').on("change", function () {
    var selectednumbers = jQuery('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    alert(selectednumbers);
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DL79Y/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to have the selected items values in an array, then use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
var selectednumbers = jQuery('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function (i, selected) {
    return this.value;
}).get();
alert(selectednumbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the checked state you can't use `val()`use the `.checked` property instead:

```
selectednumbers[i] = selected.checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the change event to the checkbox

```
jQuery('input[type=checkbox]').on("change",function(){

    var selectednumbers = [];
    jQuery('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(i, selected) {
        selectednumbers[i] = selected.value + ' : ' + selected.checked;
    });
    alert(selectednumbers);

})
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/nM7Ty/2/)